# how to return argument from the exe after createprocess ends?

Tags: c++, wpf, vb.net, visual-c++

I have opened a exe file using create process in vc++ and passed argument through it, I just want to know how to get a argument from the exe to the vc++ program after the exe is closed.

**My Create process Code**

```
    STARTUPINFO si;     
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

   ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
   si.cb = sizeof(si);
   ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );
   char  strcrt[256];

    char * str = path;

    char buf[256] = "buffer ";
    strcat (buf, str);

    LPTSTR cmdArgs = TEXT(buf);

  if (
    CreateProcess
            (
            TEXT("C:\\MatrixPlugin\\AdobePlugin.exe"),
            cmdArgs,NULL,NULL,FALSE,
            CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,
            NULL,NULL,
            &si,
            &pi
            )
            )
        {
            WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
        }

    CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
    CloseHandle( pi.hThread );
    }
```

**This code starts a vb.net WPF code name AdobePlugin, 
Code for this is**

```
Private Sub App_Startup(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As StartupEventArgs)
    If (e.Args.Length <> 0) Then
        MsgBox(e.Args(0))
    Else
        MsgBox("Please open a PDF document first.")
    End If
    Dim Send As String = "c:\help\help_123.pdf"
    'here I want to sent this string to the vc++ code. 
    'I dont want return true or false
    'But I want to return a string contains a address in it.
    'Window.Close()

End Sub
```

Please Some help me through this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the return data is integer, you can use process exit codes and GetExitCodeProcess. If it's more complex data, you could use inter-process communication, like reading the output stream of the executing process (there's a field for that in STARTUPINFO structure)

Comment: Can you give me some code for this inter-process communication, where i have to insert this in to my code...!

Comment: For example, if you use exits codes, after WaitForSingleObject you add something like DWORD result; GetExitCodeProcess(pi.hProcess, &result); and then use value in result

Answer (score 1):

if the starter application can have a window with message loop, the easiest is probably to just post a `WM_COPYDATA` message to that window.